# how to set innerhtml of div

Tags: c#, .net, string

please help me
this my C# code behind

```
  SpecialOffersDiv.InnerHtml = "<div class="offer_box_wide">
                                  <a href=""><img src="../images/p1.jpg" width="130" height="98" class="img_left" alt="" border="0" /></a>
                                  <div class="offer_info"> <span>For Sale 150 000 $</span>
                                  <p class="offer"> &quot;Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
                                  <div class="more"><a href="#">...more</a></div>
                                  </div>
                                  </div>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problems are being caused by two things. First, the double-quote marks within the string need to be escaped. Second, the new lines need to be handled appropriately. There are two ways to accomplish this.

First, you could use the verbatim string literal indicator and then double each double-quote mark in the string.

```
SpecialOffersDiv.InnerHtml = @"<div class=""offer_box_wide"">
                               <a href=""""><img src=""../images/p1.jpg"" width=""130"" height=""98"" class=""img_left"" alt="""" border=""0"" /></a>
                               <div class=""offer_info""> <span>For Sale 150 000 $</span>
                               <p class=""offer""> &quot;Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
                               <div class=""more""><a href=""#"">...more</a></div>
                               </div>
                               </div>";
```

Second, you could escape the double-quotes with a backslash and change the newlines to \n:

```
SpecialOffersDiv.InnerHtml = "<div class=\"offer_box_wide\">\n" +
                             "<a href=\"\"><img src=\"../images/p1.jpg\" width=\"130\" height=\"98\" class=\"img_left\" alt=\"\" border=\"0\" /></a>\n" +
                             "<div class=\"offer_info\"><span>For Sale 150 000 $</span>\n<p class=\"offer\"> &quot;Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>\n" +
                             "<div class=\"more\"><a href=\"#\">...more</a></div>\n" +
                             "</div>\n" +
                             "<`div>";
```

I'd say go with the first, it looks much nicer.

Answer (score 2):

[String literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (especially see the example `string f & g`)

```
SpecialOffersDiv.InnerHtml = @"<div class=""offer_box_wide"">
                        <a href=""""><img src=""../images/p1.jpg"" width=""130"" height=""98"" class=""img_left"" alt="""" border=""0"" /></a>
                        <div class=""offer_info""> <span>For Sale 150 000 $</span>
                        <p class=""offer""> &quot;Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
                        <div class=""more""><a href=""#"">...more</a></div>
                        </div>
                        </div>";
```